# printf a buffer with nulls

Tags: c++, c, printf, packet

Is there some fancy printf syntax to ignore nulls when printing a string?

Example use case: printing a network packet that contains a bunch of null terminated strings.

My test code to illustrate the issue:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void main()
{
    char buffer[32];
    const char h[] = "hello";
    const char w[] = "world";
    const int size = sizeof(w) + sizeof(h);

    memcpy(buffer, h, sizeof(h));
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(h), w, sizeof(w));

    //try printing stuff with printf
    printf("prints only 'hello' [%s]\n",buffer);
    printf("this prints '<bunch of spaces> hello' [%*s]\n",size,buffer);
    printf("and this prints 'hello' [%.*s]\n",size,buffer);

    //hack fixup code
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == 0)
            buffer[i] = ' ';
    }
    printf("this prints 'hello world ' [%.*s]\n",size,buffer);
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is wrong.  Make it `int main()` for C++, `int main(void)` for C.  (Since you're using `<cstdio>` and `<cstring>`, you're obviously using C++, so it should be `int main()`.)

Comment: Your example is very distinctly a blend of C and C++, which is fine but you can expect to receive a variety of answers.

Comment: It is true, I use a blend of C++ and c. C++ is great for getting things going quickly. C is fast. I tagged 'c' because of the use of printf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` assumes strings are c-style (i.e. ending in null characters).  You need to do one of the following:

1) use the `write` method of ostream (C++ style)

2) use the `write` command (from `unistd.h`, C style)

3) iterate through each character and print.

When I am debugging packets, oftentimes I will print out each character using the `%02hhx` format to be sure I see the exact code (without any quirks about printing null characters to the screen)

Comment: Sadly the answer is No. But `fwrite(buffer, 1, size, stdout);` works for C++. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to tell `printf` the length of the string you want to print. You'll need to print each character individually:

```
void printbuf(const char* buffer, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
}

char buf[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 'a', 'b', 'c'};
printbuf(buf, 7);

// prints
// abc abc
```

You *could* wrap the buffer in a `string` and print that (if you don't mind the duplication), since `NULL`s do not delimit `string`s:

```
char buf[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 'a', 'b', 'c'};

string strwithnulls(buf, buf + 7); // or as John pointed out, string strwithnulls(buf, 7);
cout << strwithnulls;

// prints
// abc abc
```

### But better yet

you could use `write` of `std::ostream`, because you are using C++ after all:

```
char buf[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 'a', 'b', 'c'};
cout.write(buf, 7); // best yet
```

If you are actually using C (why'd you tag it C++?) you can do this:

```
char buf[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0, 'a', 'b', 'c'};
fwrite(buf, 1, 7, stdout);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `string strwithnulls(buf, 7)`?

Comment: @John it can be either one since one overload takes a `char*` and a length and another one takes a beginning and end iterator.

Comment: I dream of the day wherein people add a comment about _why_ they are downvoting an answer _before_ they actually click the button. Pointless and useless downvote is pointless and useless without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that comes to mind, so why not use fwrite() instead. This works assuming you know the format of the contents of your buffer.

```
fwrite(buffer, size, 1, stdout);
```

If you require further formatted output you can use printf() before and after the call to fwrite().

I am not responding with references to typical C++ iostreams because I got the impression you preferred something in standard C.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your `memcpy` operations copy six bytes each, since both `"hello"` and `"world"` are `char[6]`, and the result is `h|e|l|l|o|\0|w|o|r|l|d|\0`. That's why you don't copy strings with `memcpy`, but rather with the cleverly named `strcpy`.

Next, "how would you print network packets"? I have a utility function `hexdump` that prints arbitrary memory in lines of sixteen, maybe you'll find it useful:

```
void asciiprint(FILE * out, unsigned char c)
{
  if (c < 32 || c > 126) fprintf(out, ".");
  else fprintf(out, "%c", c);
}

void hexdump(FILE * out, const unsigned char * buf, size_t length, const char * delim)
{
  for (size_t k = 0; 16*k < length; k++)
  {
    fprintf(out, "%s", delim);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16 && 16*k + i < length; ++i)
      fprintf(out, "0x%02X ", buf[16*k + i]);

    if (16*(k+1) > length)
      for (size_t i = 0; i < 16*(k+1)-length; ++i)
        fprintf(out, "     ");

    fprintf(out, "    ");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16 && 16*k + i < length; ++i)
      asciiprint(out, buf[16*k + i]);

    fprintf(out, "\n");
  }
}
```

Usage: `hexdump(stdout, (const unsigned char*)buffer, 32, "==> ");`

Comment: First off, your post was very rude. Second off, strcpy is both unsafe and slower than memcpy. Thirdly, and this is probably my fault, the intent is to quickly print something for debugging purposes. I already demonstrated a quick fix to get what I wanted, the extra code you posted was unnecessary.

Comment: @Chad: `memcpy` or `strcpy` are both as unsafe as the programmer using them.  With `memcpy`, you need to use the smaller of the two sizes (source size and destination size).  With `strcpy`, you need to know both the sizes to be sure you are not doing bad things.  Either way, you *have* to know both the source and the destination sizes for either of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to ignore nulls, or print them in some visible form?

Assuming the latter, and borrowing @Seth's code:

```
void printbuf(const char* buffer, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        if (buffer[i] == '\0') {
             cout << "\\0";
        }
        else
            cout << buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `cout << ...` if you're using C rather than C++.